# How do I add local Kafka topic as lambda event source

Tags: apache-kafka, aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli

I’m new to lambda, my requirement is to write a lambda function to poll messages from a Kafka topic process them and store in db. All this requirement is to be done on local machine using spring boot application, not on AWS. I have created a spring application, added a requestHandler, and using Sam cli to run it, now for the request handler I have to input Kafka topic as event source, how do I add that in the template.yaml. Here is what I have so far

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description:Sample SAM Template
Resources:
  RequestFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: target/aws-sam-java-rest-1.0.0.jar
      Handler: com.amazonaws.handler.RequestHandler::handleRequest
      Runtime: java8
      Events:
        ……………..
```

Not sure what to add in the events parts as I’m using the Kafka on local host. Found some examples like this but didn’t find any for local Kafka setup. What should be the type and SourceAccessConfigurations for Kafka on local machine

```
Events:
  SelfManagedKafkaEvent:
    Type: SelfManagedKafka
    Properties:
      BatchSize: 1000
      Enabled: true
      KafkaBootstrapServers:
        - abc.xyz.com:xxxx
      SourceAccessConfigurations: 
        -  Type: BASIC_AUTH
           URI: arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-west-2:123456789012:secret:my-path/my-secret-name-1a2b3c
      Topics:
        - MyKafkaTopic
```

Comment: 1) How exactly are you running lambda locally? 2) Assuming lambda is running locally, have you tried putting `localhost:9092` in `KafkaBootstrapServers:`? 3) Why do you need lambda when Spring Boot / Spring Kafka exist?

Comment: It is not spring app, just Java application, lambda to pull messages from Kafka and send to what should I place source access configurations, I’m using Sam cli to run lambda

Comment: Okay - can you answer second question I asked?

Comment: Yeah I have tried that and next to that is SourceAccessConfiguration not sure what to fill in

Comment: I don't think that's a required property. You're running Kafka locally without authentication, so no access controls are needed